# JavaFx two diffrent classes in tableview and tablecolumn

Tags: java, javafx

My problem is that I have two different classes : "Book" and "User".
I want to display Books in my table after clicking button "Show all books" and then all Users in this same table after clicking button "show all users". I don't know what type I should give in tableview and tablecolumn.

What can i put instead of "?" ?

```
public class WorkerPaneController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableView<?> tab;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> c3;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> c4;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> c5;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> c6;

@FXML
private Button test;

@FXML
private ComboBox<String> wybor;

@FXML
private Button show;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Data, ?> c1;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> c2;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

this.wybor.getItems().addAll("Książek", "Egzemplarzy", "Czytelników", 
"Pracowników");

}

@FXML
public void ChangeScene(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    Parent userMenu = 
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/LibDB/view/UserPane.fxml"));

    Stage s = new Stage();
    s.setTitle("test");
    s.setScene(new Scene(userMenu));
    s.show();
}

@FXML
public void pokaz(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    if (wybor.getValue() != null) {
        switch (this.wybor.getValue()) {
        case "Czytelników":
            c1.setText("id_czytelnika");
            c2.setText("Imie");
            c3.setText("Nazwisko");
            c4.setText("Wiek");
            c5.setText("PESEL");
            c6.setText("id_adresu");
            break;
        case "Pracowników":
            c1.setText("id_czytelnika");
            c2.setText("Imie");
            c3.setText("Nazwisko");
            c4.setText("Wiek");
            c5.setText("PESEL");
            c6.setText("id_adresu");
            break;
        case "Książek":
            c1.setText("id_ksiazki");
            c2.setText("Tytul");
            c3.setText("Ilosc stron");
            c4.setText("ISBN");
            c5.setText("Rok Wydania");
            c6.setText("id_wydawnictwa");
            break;
        case "Egzemplarzy":
            c1.setText("id_egzemplarza");
            c2.setText("Numer katalogowy");
            c3.setText("id_Typ okladki");
            c4.setText("Numer ksiazki");
            c5.setText("opis");
            c6.setText("Dostepnosc");
            break;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

}

public void initPracownikow() {

    // c1.setCellValueFactory(data ->
    // data.getValue().getUzytkownicy().get(0).getImieProperty());
}
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure: You've got 4 different types you want to display in the same table and you always want to display the same number of columns you want to display and probably the common supertype is `Object`? Then you need to go with `Object`!

Comment: Simply build 4 different tables and set as content on every button click the right table with the right data. This would result a clean and understandable code. As I can see you have the same amount of properties in each model, then maybe you can use a single Model class, and update it at every change with the right data. This approach would result less code but it would be also less understandable.

Comment: @Sunflame the problem is that I don't know how to set up the table. As a type I can put "Book" or "User", this is this problem.